# Strange logs in apache?

Tags: apache, url, logging, wamp

I have apache with version 2.22 and have these rare logs with IPs from Japan, Taiwan ...

```
218.52.178.3 - - [10/Feb/2015:13:48:48 +0100] "\xa6Q\xb0\xce\xf5\b\x15\x05\xd3\xaf\xbe\x1d\xac\xbf\x99lx\xbf\xb0\x16w{\xb3\xf4\xa5%\xd6\x16\xd0\x15\xd5\xfa\xcbqo\xae9\xc2\x13\xf5&\x91\xb7\x90\xa1\xe5W\xe3" 200 62

98.119.71.85 - - [10/Feb/2015:15:48:47 +0100] "\x86}\x12%\xe8<\xc9\xb8\xed\xb9\x9d4j+0-\x19\xb9\xd3\xafA\xa9@7\x04q\x17\xe3\xa4\x87\xd3\t\x04\x92\x8493X\xd3H?\xf1\xb8\x96\x11\xbf\xc9\xddQ" 400 226
```

Does anyone know what they mean?

Comment: Your site is being probed for exploits

Answer (score 0):

This is some kind of crawler, checking for vulnerabilities. You can block them by IP. Howevere They change the IP constantly.

Create a .htaccess file in your Document root and insert this in to it

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from 218.52.178.3
Deny from 98.119.71.85
```

If you have access to your firewall you can block hem from there. Each firewall has a different way to block IPs.

Answer (score 0):

This is the requests made in Eastern languages by UTF encoding. Hieroglyphs . Apache converts it to english letters. They can be decoded to origin using some online services.

Comment: Would you leave the link of one of these online services which can decode such that `$request` into meaningful strings?